# vCard import issue when content is too long on Android

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I'm using Sabre/vobject ([Documentation](http://sabre.io/vobject/vcard/) [GitHub](https://github.com/sabre-io/vobject)) using php to create vCard version 3.0.
As stated in the format of [vCard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-3.2)

> Content lines SHOULD be folded to a maximum width of 75 octets

The Sabre library handle it correctly and fold the lines in the right place. When adding the vCard to iPhone contacts app, all works as expected. On Android when the address is less than 75 bytes all works well, but once the address is longer and the content folds into multiple lines, the address doesn't appear on the contact. At least when using the default contact app on Pixel 3, Android 10.

If I change the vCard manually, and keep the whole address in one line of more than 75 bytes, **not** as expected by the format, then the contacts app is adding the address well.

Is it just a bug on the Android contacts app? I didn't find anything about this issue. Am I doing something wrong? Any solution?

The following vCard, doesn't add the address to the contact on Android

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Sabre//Sabre VObject 3.4.5//EN
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:vCard test 3
N;CHARSET=utf-8:test 3;vCard;;;
ADR;TYPE=work;CHARSET=utf-8:;;336 Rue Saint-Honoré;Paris;Île-de-France;75
 001;France
GEO:48.865928, 2.330285
EMAIL;TYPE=work;CHARSET=utf-8:abcdef@gmail.com
TEL;TYPE=mobile:+1 212 1234 5678
TEL;TYPE=landline:+1 977 1234 5678
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:CEO
END:VCARD
```

The following vCard add the address to the contact. Please note, the format is wrong the address line has more than 75 bytes.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Sabre//Sabre VObject 3.4.5//EN
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:vCard test 3
N;CHARSET=utf-8:test 3;vCard;;;
ADR;TYPE=work;CHARSET=utf-8:;;336 Rue Saint-Honoré;Paris;Île-de-France;75001;France
GEO:48.865928, 2.330285
EMAIL;TYPE=work;CHARSET=utf-8:abcdef@gmail.com
TEL;TYPE=mobile:+1 212 1234 5678
TEL;TYPE=landline:+1 977 1234 5678
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:CEO
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @NicolasRizzo unfortunately no.
It looks like a bug to me. I hope Google will fix it soon